# filter dataset with dplyr depeding on the max value retrieved from group by

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a df called nycbikes18 , I want to get the most frequent bike (bike id most used)
then retrieve all the data for this id

here is my code and it is working very well
but I want to have it all through the pipe

```
nycbikes18 %>% 
  group_by(bikeid) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) 

nycbikes18[nycbikes18$bikeid==26288,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two option using pipes in `dplyr`. I'll use `mtcars` as an example :

Using `count` and join

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  left_join(mtcars, by = 'cyl')

#   cyl  mpg  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1    8 18.7 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#2    8 14.3 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#3    8 16.4 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#4    8 17.3 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#5    8 15.2 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#6    8 10.4 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#7    8 10.4 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#8    8 14.7 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#9    8 15.5 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#10   8 15.2 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#11   8 13.3 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#12   8 19.2 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#13   8 15.8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#14   8 15.0 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Or using `add_count` :

```
mtcars %>%
  add_count(cyl) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't get the same results

Comment: You haven't shared your data so there is no way for me to confirm your claim. As shown in my example answer with `mtcars` that it works to filter the data with most frequent data.